# ValidationExpression for a special date format

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, date

I need to use the `RegularExpressionValidator`. It has to check the correct format. I have found this nice working expression:

```
^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$
```

But I need this Expression not for `dd/mm/yyyy`. My date format should be `dd.mm.yyyy`.

How to transform this expression?

Answer (score 0):

It look like only thing that need to be changes is all `\/` to `\.` so it should be

```
^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\.(0[13578]|1[02])\.((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\.(0[13456789]|1[012])\.((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\.02\.((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\.02\.((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$
```

Answer (score 0):

try it

```
/^(?:(0[1-9]|1[012])[\. \/.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\. \/.](19|20)[0-9]{2})$/
```

or

```
^((((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])[\.\-\/](0?[13578]|1[02])[\.\-\/]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0?[1-9]|[12]\d|30)[\.\-\/](0?[13456789]|1[012])[\.\-\/]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])[\.\-\/]0?2[\.\-\/]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|(29[\.\-\/]0?2[\.\-\/]((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)|00)))|(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(0[13578]|1[02])((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)(0[13456789]|1[012])((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])02((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}))|(2902((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)|00))))$
```